# Laravel: How to get the next highest value in database?

Tags: database, laravel

Assuming that I have this score column in my database;

41 41 45 48 50

I have a $number variable which is equal to 42. then, I tried to query like this.

```
$search = DB::table('scores')->where('score', $number)->orderByRaw('RAND()')->first();
```

Of course, the result will be NULL. What should I do to get the next highest value which is 45?

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why 45? The highest is 50? Please explain what you want to achieve

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek The *next* highest number after 42 in his list is 45.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How would you do it in raw SQL? You want the next score greater than `$number`. So limit your result with `->where('score','>',$number)` then `->orderBy('score')` (ascending) so that the first row will contain the next score greater than `$number`, and then fetch just the first row.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I am getting a weird result. If ever my score is 3, the result will be 30. If the score is 2 the result will be 20 instead of 5 which is the nearest highest score.
Btw, my data is almost consist of 400 scores on my tables.

$secondsearch = DB::table('scores')->where('score', '>=', $score)->orderBy('score', 'ASC')->take(1)->first();

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = DB::table('scores')->where('score','>', $number)->orderBy('score', 'asc')->take(1)->get();
```

That should work.

Peace!

Answer (score 0):

You should use for that:

```
$search = DB::table('scores')->where('score', '>' $number)->orderBy('score', 'ASC')->first();
```